# How to send image from client to server by flask python

Tags: python, flask, post, server, client

I've tried to send an image from client to server like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaXfb.png). But server can not read image and return Exept.
Plese help me. Thank you very much.

```
server.py

if format_type in ['file', 'url']:
        if format_type == 'file':
            try:
                image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(request.files["img1"].read()))
            except:
                ret = create_respone({}, '3', 'Incorrect image format')
                return ret
```

```
client.py

import requests
url = "http://192.168.254.217:5000/predict?format_type=file&get_thumb=false"
file = {'file': open('image0.jpg', 'rb').read()}
response = requests.post(url = url, files=file)
print(response.text)
```

The result is Except.  How can i send a image from client to server.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there, help yourselves with the changes below:

Currently not able to infer format_type variable. but guessing from the request format below should work.

server.py

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    format_type = request.args.get('format_type', default=None)

    if format_type in ['file', 'url']:
        if format_type == 'file':
            try:
                image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(request.files["img1"].read()))
                return jsonify({'message': 'Success!'})
            except:
                ret = create_respone({}, '3', 'Incorrect image format')
                return ret

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

client.py

```
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict?format_type=file&get_thumb=false"
file = {'img1': open('image0.jpg', 'rb')}
response = requests.post(url=url, files=file)
print(response.text)
```

The only change I did was I bound the port to 127.0.0.1, you need to change it according to your need.

Hope this helps.